# SpringBoot Service Injection using private final not working

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to springboot and am trying to follow this example: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-caching-2

In my app I keep getting "**error: variable myApplicationService not initialized in the default constructor**" but in comparison to the tutorial I am following, I don't understand how it gets initialized, this is my controller:

```
package com.springbootredis.controllers;

import com.springbootredis.service.MyApplicationService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class PersonController {

    private final MyApplicationService myApplicationService;//ERROR HERE

    @GetMapping("/uuid")
    public String generateRandomUUID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @GetMapping("/addperson/{name}")
    public String addPerson(@PathVariable String name) {
        String ret = myApplicationService.addNewPerson(name);
        return "Added person with name: " + name + " and id: " + ret;
    }


    @GetMapping("/deleteperson/{id}")
    public String deletePerson(@PathVariable String id) {
        String ret = myApplicationService.delete(id);
        return "Deleted person. ID:" + id + " Name: " + ret;
    }

    @GetMapping("/updateperson/{id}/{name}")
    public String updatePerson(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String name) {
        myApplicationService.updatePerson(id, name);
        return "Updated person. ID:" + id + " with Name: " + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getperson/{id}")
    public String getPerson(@PathVariable String id) {
        String ret = myApplicationService.findById(id);
        return "Got person. ID:" + id + " Name: " + ret;
    }
}
```

I tried autowired annotation but it says it is not recommended, and the build still fails. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.7.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.7.1")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.1")

    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29")

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using lombok but haven't configured lombok in your build (you only have the dependency for compile time). Rendering the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation useless and not creating an all args constructor. If you are learning Spring Boot, ditch Lombok as that adds additional overhead in things that can go wrong. Remove the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation and just add a constructor that fulfills the contract. Also (pro-tip) remove the versions from the dependencies (you are actually mixing 2.7.0 and 2.7.1 dependencies which eventually will lead to issues).

Comment: Also you aren't following the tutorial als you are using Gradle and not Maven and a newer Spring Boot version. If you are following a tutorial stick with the tutorial (and experiment afterwards).

Comment: @M.Deinum there is no need for a runtime dependency on Lombok, as the required classes are generated at compile-time via annotation proccesing. From the code as-is, it should work, so I'm assuming that there might be an IDE issue (no annotation processing enabled).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, so it turns out I needed to add:
 ```annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
 annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")```
to the build.gradle file under dependencies and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Edit: (For completeness' sake) As you've already found out, the `annotationProcessor` entry for Lombok is missing from your `build.gradle` file. In addition, your Lombok entry can be `compileOnly` and does not need to be included at runtime.

Original Answer follows.

---

Your code as-is should still work. As mentioned by @m-deinum, you should also avoid doing manual dependency management on Spring versions.

That said, Lombok does its magic via *Annotation Processing*, a feature that might not be enabled by default in your IDE Project.

One possible culprit for your error is that this feature is disabled, hence Lombok is not generating the constructor and only a default, no-args constructor is available. Once you enable it, the compile-error should go away.

That said, I've found `@AllArgsConstructor` to not be very robust when designing classes. Prefer `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or simply explicit constructors and design your classes to have immutable state.

Comment: It isn't that the IDE isn't setup correctly, grade isn't either. As yo need to setup annotation processing and add Lombok to it. So no it currently won't work as is.

Comment: On that, i am using the latest intellij, and i couldnt find the lombok plugin under the plugin market place, looks like lombok might be a bit behind there but still got it working with fixing the gradle.build by adding the annotation processors

Comment: @M.Deinum You are correct, since Gradle was missing the `annotationProcessor` entry. The existing Lombok entry should also be `compileOnly`. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve my issue I added the following to the build.gradle file under the dependencies section:

```
annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
```